# ACL group structure: top down or bottom up?

Tags: permissions, acl

I've put together an [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)  permissions system into my application and I'm now wondering about how best to use it, especially in regards to user groups. In it's simplest form, there will be several "role" groups ("admins", "editors", "users", etc) and all users will belong to one of these groups.

My question is: in your experience, is it better* to structure the ARO tree to have the most permissions at the top and remove them as you go down (1) or to have the least permissions at the top and add them as you go down (2).

```
(1):
- Admins          allow all
  - Editors       deny create, delete
    - Users       deny update

(2):
- Users           allow read
  - Editors       allow update
    - Admins      allow create, delete
```

What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is "Should a User be and Admin without various abilities, or should an Admin be a User with extra abilities." I think, from a modeling perspective, having an Admin be a User is better.

Also, its important to think about what could go wrong. If there was some misconfiguration in the implementation of the system, it would be better security to risk denying someone access to do something that they should be able to do, rather than risk allowing someone access to something that they should not have access to.

Thus, I think your second example is better. Its more secure to structure your system in terms of granting permissions, rather than denying them.